# Emails not showing up in Email enabled Document Library of sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have correctly configured a doc library to receive emails. Now, when I send an email it is being received by the doc library but not showing it in the library as an item. The reason I am so sure that this library is receiving mails is that, an email event receiver is running on this library which will add an item in another list if this Doc Library receives an Email.

So, why am I not able to see any mails I send to this library even though they are being received. I am not able to figure what could have gone wrong. Can someone please kindly advice me why this is happening and provide me any valuable solution to resolve this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register SPEmailEventReceiver incoming mails are handled by it and are not stored in Document library. It is up to your implementation how the mail is processed (and possibly stored).

Comment: Hi Mazin..Thank you for looking into this. I have another document library which does exactly the same functionality as above and even have an event receiver running on it. When a mail is sent..it is going to the **"Drop"** folder of **InetPub** and Sharepoint is picking it from there and it is being shown in the library and removing it from the "Drop" folder. However, is not happening with a new library I have created and followed exact same steps. The email is coming to **"Drop"** folder and is getting deleted after some time but not showing in the Library. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: SMTP is using Drop folder for storing incoming emails that are addressed to local users. When they are taken by users (via e.g. POP3 or IMAP protocol) the emails are removed from Drop folder. They are also removed when they time-out (they are not taken by user for a defined period of time).

Comment: Thanks for the explaination..Now I understood. But how come one Document Libray is able to show the Emails and the other could not?

Comment: Are you REALLY sure that the configuration is the same? As I wrote if you register your own SPEmailEventReceiver emails are not stored. There might be another receiver processing emails and storing them. From my point of view the suspicious one is that Document library that has event receiver registered and saves emails. Maybe event receiver is not registered correctly.